# Filtering a many-to-many relationship with Django's Q query

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-q

I have a model

```
class Book(models.Model):

    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    authors = models.ManyToManyField(Author)

class Author(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

And I have a view

```
class SearchResultsListView(ListView):
    model = Book
    context_object_name = 'book_list'
    template_name = 'book/search_results.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        query = self.request.GET.get('q')
        return Book.objects.filter(
            Q(title__icontains=query)
        )
```

I can't figure out how to access foreignkeys. How do I do a Q query searching for say, "show me only books in which any authors of the book that have the query string in any part of their last name"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can look "through" a relation with two consecutive underscores (`__`). So here you can filter on books where the `last_name` of the author contains a certain substring with:

```
Book.objects.filter(
    authors__last_name__icontains=query
)
```

If you thus look for `Book`s where the title contains the given `query`, *or* the `last_name` of one of the authors contains the `query`, then you can filter with:

```
Book.objects.filter(
    Q(title__icontains=query) |
    Q(authors__last_name__icontains=query)
)
```